# argocd with a wildcard certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, argocd

I am using AWS NLB and therefore SSL should happen at the argocd (1.7.8) side. However it seems nothing I do argocd always uses self-signed cert.

```
➜ curl -vvI https://argocd-dev.example.com
*   Trying 54.18.49.47:443...
* Connected to argocd-dev.example.com (54.18.49.47) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

this is my ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd-dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: argocd-server
          servicePort: https
```

this is how I start argocd-server:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - argocd-server
        - --staticassets
        - /shared/app
        - --loglevel 
        - debug
        - --client-certificate 
        - /var/ssl-cert/tls.crt
        - --client-key
        - /var/ssl-cert/tls.key
        image: argoproj/argocd:v1.7.8
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: argocd-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 8083
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 30
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/config/ssh
          name: ssh-known-hosts
        - mountPath: /app/config/tls
          name: tls-certs
        - mountPath: /var/ssl-cert
          name: ssl-cert
          readOnly: true
      serviceAccountName: argocd-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: static-files
      - configMap:
          name: argocd-ssh-known-hosts-cm
        name: ssh-known-hosts
      - configMap:
          name: argocd-tls-certs-cm
        name: tls-certs
      - name: ssl-cert
        secret:
          secretName: tls-secret
```

Comment: Did you try changing the servicePort to `http`?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/ingress/

ArgoCD has some unusual configuration that is required.

Either you need to start Argo in http (insecure) mode if your load balancer is doing the SSL or you need to pass your secret into the Kubernetes Ingress.

Answer (score 0):

Argo CD expects certificate and certificate key in the `tls.crt` and `tls.key` keys of `argocd-secret` Secret: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/operator-manual/argocd-secret.yaml#L11

Restart is not required - a new certificate should be used as soon as the secret is updated.